# Filtering Ext.data.Store using exactMatch in Sencha Touch application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to filter a list of items using the exactMatch in order to get items with the exact ID :

This code is working fine but it returns all the items which the ID begins with the required one :

```
itemslist.getStore().filter('type_id',this.getType().getValue());
```

If the value of the type ID is 1, it returns all the elements which the type has an ID like 1XXX. But I want only the elements which the type is exactly 1.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195190/filtering-a-ext-data-store-by-a-particular-id-returns-multiple-results) so I changed the code to use the exactMatch but it doesn't work, this is my code :

```
itemslist.getStore().filter({
    property: 'type_id',
    value: this.getType().getValue(),
    exactMatch: true
});
```

Even if I delete the exactMatch line, it doesn't work and the result is empty. Could you tell me please what's the difference between these 2 ways and how to get exactMatch working ? Thanks

Comment: Try this : `itemslist.getStore().filter(Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {property: "type_id", value: this.getType().getValue(), exactMatch: true}));` Not sure this makes a change but sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
itemslist.getStore().filter(Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
  property: "type_id",
  value: this.getType().getValue(), 
  exactMatch: true
}));
```

Not sure this makes a change but sometimes...