# Filtering a Sencha Touch 2 store to match field exactly with int value

Tags: javascript, regex, filter, sencha-touch-2, datastore

I am trying to filter a ST2 store to exactly find items with a certain id. By default ST2 filters stores using the LIKE operator and this does not work for finding exact int (id) matches. After some search I found that I need to use regex to do this but I can't figure out the correct regex. Here's my code:

```
var categoriesStore = Ext.getStore('categories');
var category_id = this.config.data.catId;
categoriesStore.filter('category_id', **regex pattern here**);
```

I have tried the following without luck:

```
/^category_id$/
```

and

```
"/^"+category_id+"$/"
```

I am sure that I'm very close.

Comment: Try `"^"+category_id+"$"`.

Comment: @Qtax I tried your suggestion and this does not seem to work. The `categorieStore` shows no items as a result of applying filter. I can see that if I run a `clearFilter()` on it all the data comes back.

Comment: see also <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195190/filtering-a-ext-data-store-by-a-particular-id-returns-multiple-results/5195241#5195241>

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the pattern to the filter you do not need to put the opening / closing slashes into the regex pattern, which is a delimiter used in some languages / command line tools.

This should work fine:

```
"^"+category_id+"$"
```

Comment: See this was also addressed by @Qtax

Answer (score 0):

There is also an exactMatch parameter that can be set in the filter object: [Filtering a Ext.data.Store by a particular id returns multiple results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195190/filtering-a-ext-data-store-by-a-particular-id-returns-multiple-results/5195241#5195241)